# How to handel no results with Android Room and RxJava 2?

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room

I have database with table contact and I want to check if there is contact with some phone number.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM contact WHERE phone_number = :number")
Flowable<Contact> findByPhoneNumber(int number);
```

I have RxJava 2 Composite disposable with statement from above to check if there is contact with phone number.

```
disposable.add(Db.with(context).getContactsDao().findByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableSubscriber<Contact>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(final Contact contact) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "phone number fined");
                    Conversation conversation;
                    if(contact != null){
                        conversation = Db.with(context).getConversationsDao().findBySender(contact.getContactId());
                        if(conversation != null){
                            conversation.setUpdatedAt(Utils.getDateAndTimeNow());
                            saveConversation(contact, conversation, context, text, phoneNumber, false);
                        } else {
                            conversation = getConversation(contact, contact.getPhoneNumber());
                            saveConversation(contact, conversation, context, text, phoneNumber, true);
                        }
                    } else {
                        conversation = Db.with(context).getConversationsDao().findByPhone(phoneNumber);
                        if(conversation != null){
                            conversation.setUpdatedAt(Utils.getDateAndTimeNow());
                            saveConversation(contact, conversation, context, text, phoneNumber, false);
                        } else {
                            conversation = getConversation(contact, phoneNumber);
                            saveConversation(contact, conversation, context, text, phoneNumber, true);
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "find phone number throwable");
                    Toast.makeText(context, t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    Log.d("TAG", "onComplete");
                }
            }));
```

This is working fine if query can find contact with required phone number, but if there is result, it nothing happens.

Here are two test cases that I wrote and they work fine:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ContactsTest {

    private AppDatabase db;

    @Rule
    public InstantTaskExecutorRule instantTaskExecutorRule =
            new InstantTaskExecutorRule();

    @Before
    public void initDb() throws Exception {
        db = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(
                InstrumentationRegistry.getContext(),
                AppDatabase.class)
                // allowing main thread queries, just for testing
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();
    }

    @After
    public void close(){
        db.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void insertAndFindTest(){
        final Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.setName("Test");
        contact.setPhoneNumber(555);
        db.contactsDao()
                .insert(contact);

        db.contactsDao().findByPhoneNumber(contact.getPhoneNumber())
                .test()
                .assertValue(new Predicate<Contact>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean test(@NonNull Contact savedContact) throws Exception {
                        if(savedContact.getPhoneNumber() == contact.getPhoneNumber()){
                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
    }

    @Test
    public void findNoValues(){
        db.contactsDao().findByPhoneNumber(333)
                .test()
                .assertNoValues();
    }

}
```

How I can solve this?

Comment: your check contact != null is useless, rxjava2 don't allow nulls. Also, do you have typo in your question? I can't understand you third sentense

Answer (score 38):

As said [here](https://medium.com/google-developers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757), you can use `Maybe` or `Single` for this case:

### Maybe

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id = :userId")
Maybe<User> getUserById(String userId);
```

Here’s what happens:

- When there is no user in the database and the query returns no rows, Maybe will complete.
- When there is a user in the database, Maybe will trigger onSuccess and it will complete.
- If the user is updated after Maybe was completed, nothing happens.

### Single

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id = :userId")
Single<User> getUserById(String userId);
```

Here are some scenarios:

- When there is no user in the database and the query returns no rows, Single will trigger onError(EmptyResultSetException.class)
- When there is a user in the database, Single will trigger onSuccess.
- If the user is updated after Single.onComplete was called, nothing happens, since the stream was completed.

It was added in version **1.0.0-alpha5**.

Comment: Is there any way to convert such single to Single<Boolean> where Boolean = "is there such row at the table?"

Comment: Important note: "If the Single<T> contains a type argument of a collection (e.g. Single<List<Song>>) then this exception (`EmptyResultSetException.class`) **is not thrown** an an empty collection is emitted instead."  [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/EmptyResultSetException.html)

Comment: One important clarification regarding Maybe -- When there is no user in the database and the query returns no rows, Maybe will complete.
When there is a user in the database, Maybe will trigger onSuccess and it will complete.

If there is a user it will not "complete" since "onComplete" is only called if the Maybe is empty

Answer (score 19):

If you want to use your entity only once, `Single` or `Maybe` is sufficient. But if you want to observe if your query is updated you can use `Flowable` and wrap your object in `List`, so when there is no results you will get empty list, and when after that, database is updated you will get another event with your result in list.

Code

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM contact WHERE phone_number = :number LIMIT 1")
Flowable<List<Contact>> findByPhoneNumber(int number)
```

I believe it's usefull in some scenarios. The drawback is that you have to access object like `resultList.get(0)`

Comment: This was a great idea and worked perfect for my use case. FYI another advantage of this method is you can check if the "list" is empty and if so return a default value down stream

Answer (score 7):

When you use `Flowable` (and `LiveData` too) as a return value in your `Dao` class then your query never stops emitting data as Room is monitoring tables for data changes. Quoting official documentation:

> Furthermore, if the response is an observable data type, such as
>   Flowable or LiveData, Room watches all tables referenced in the query
>   for invalidation.

Not sure what's the best way of handling such situation but what worked for me was a good old `.timeout()` operator. Please have a look at the following test and follow comments:

```
@Test
public void shouldCompleteIfForced() throws InterruptedException {
    // given
    TestScheduler testScheduler = new TestScheduler();

    // when asking db for non existent project
    TestSubscriber<Project> test = projectDao.getProject("non existent project")
            .timeout(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS, testScheduler)
            .test();

    // then hang forever waiting for first emission which will never happen
    // as there is no such project
    test.assertNoValues();
    test.assertNotComplete();
    test.assertNoErrors();

    // when time passes and we trigger timeout() operator
    testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    // then finally break stream with TimeoutException error ...
    test.assertError(TimeoutException.class);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you also could use wrapper with Single. Like:

```
public class QueryResult<D> {
            public D data;
            public QueryResult() {}

            public QueryResult(D data) {
                this.data = data;
            }

            public boolean isEmpty(){
                return data != null;
            }
 }
```

And use it like:

```
public Single<QueryResult<Transaction>> getTransaction(long id) {
            return createSingle(() -> database.getTransactionDao().getTransaction(id))
                    .map(QueryResult::new);
}
```

Where `createAsyncSingle`:

```
protected <T> Single<T> createSingle(final Callable<T> func) {
            return Single.create(emitter -> {
                try {
                    T result = func.call();
                    emitter.onSuccess(result);

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "Error of operation with db");
                }
            });
}
```

Don't forget to use IO thread.

Answer (score 0):

```java
@Query("SELECT * FROM contact WHERE phone_number = :number")
Flowable<List<Contact>> findByPhoneNumber(int number);
```

then

```
Optional<Contact> queryPhone(int number) {
   findByPhoneNumber(number).map { list ->
      if (list.isEmpt()) return Optional.empty() else return Optional.of(list[0])
   }
}
```

as described [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757)

I find it's strange that this behaviour is no where to be found on official docs though

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer using `java.util.Optional`. Your code will look like:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM contact WHERE phone_number = :number")
Flowable<Optional<Contact>> findByPhoneNumber(int number);
```

And then

```
findByPhoneNumber(number).map(optionalContact -> {
    if (optionalContact.isPresent()) {
        return optionalContact.get();
    } else {
        // no contact present, use default value or something
    }
})
```